# C# - BulkDescriptor() method in NEST library overwriting the data

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am new to ES and I am using vesion 7.x. I am trying to index a list of POCO class object, but the bulkdescriptor is only overwriting the data and the last object in the List is getting indexed. I am trying to index all the items in "myindex" index.

I have tried to index one by one through for loop but it takes time and i came across this BulkDescriptor Method.

This is the code that I am using for indexing:

ESClient:

```
public ElasticClient EsClient()
{
  ConnectionSettings(connectionPool).DisableDirectStreaming();
  Uri EsInstance = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
  ConnectionSettings EsConfiguration = new 
  ConnectionSettings(EsInstance).DefaultIndex("myindex");
  ElasticClient esClient = new ElasticClient(EsConfiguration);
  return esClient;            
}
```

Code for Indexing:

```
var bulkIndexer = new BulkDescriptor();

foreach (var item in items)
{
   bulkIndexer.Index<IndexDataItem>(i => i
                        .Document(item)
                        .Id(item.Id));

}
var bulkIndexResponse = _connectionToEs.EsClient().Bulk(b => bulkIndexer);
```

I have also tried to add this `var bulkIndexResponse = _connectionToEs.EsClient().Bulk(b => bulkIndexer);` in the foreach loop but it results in the same result.

Here is my POCO Class:

```
public class IndexDataItem
{
    public IndexDataItem()
    {
        DateModified = DateTime.Now;
        DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public string FullText { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }

    public DocumentLevel DocumentLevel { get; set; } 

    public IndexDataField[] Fields { get; set; }
}
```

I want all the list objects to be indexed under "myindex". Can anybody help on this.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Are you sure all of the objects in `items` have unique id? Could you also share `bulkIndexResponse.DebugInformation`?

Comment: Thanks @Rob, the ids were 0 in this case. And i think that is the reason why it was overwriting. I changed the id to a random number and I will check if this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Rob may have suggested what the problem is in this case in the comments, but I wanted to add some additional info to help get you started.

Using the `Bulk()` API allows you to send bulk requests of operations to Elasticsearch. If you need to index a *very* large amount of documents, you'll need to send multiple bulk requests to do so, handling retries and failures, if they occur. For this, you may consider [using the `BulkAll()` API in NEST](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/indexing-documents.html#_multiple_documents_with_bulkallobservable_helper), which is a .NET client abstraction for sending bulk operations from an `IEnumerable<T>` of documents

```cs
public static IEnumerable<IndexDataItem> GetItems()
{
    var count = 0;

    while (count < 1_000_000)
    {
        yield return new IndexDataItem { Id = count + 1 };
        count++;
    }
}

var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
    .DefaultIndex("myindex");

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

var bulkAllObservable = client.BulkAll(GetItems(), b => b
    .BackOffTime("30s") 
    .BackOffRetries(2) 
    .RefreshOnCompleted()
    .MaxDegreeOfParallelism(Environment.ProcessorCount)
    .Size(1000) 
)
.Wait(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60), next => 
{
    // do something e.g. write number of pages to console
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Russ, this really helped me to understand the mistakes that i was doing and I was able to index and search the items.